# Do I do more work if I pull on a rope that is 1) attached to a wall or 2) attached to a movable column?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, work, free-body-diagram, string

Let's say I'm standing on a frictionless floor, and there's a rope attached to a wall or movable column. I pull on the rope with a constant force. Clearly I must move towards the wall/column, so I do work. After applying the force for time $t$, have I done the same amount of work in both cases? If not, in which case do I do more work?

I would guess that I do more work when the rope is attached to the column, because by conservation of momentum, the column would also start moving towards me - and if it's moving, it's got KE which must have come from me. But this reasoning seems rather weak. Perhaps I do the same amount of work for example, and the difference in energy manifests as a slower speed by me.

I'm looking for an analysis of this system and the work I do.

Answer (score 1):

You do more work if you are pulling on a moveable column rather than a fixed wall.

Remember, work is a transfer of energy. The “work” that you do accelerating yourself doesn’t transfer energy, so it isn’t actually work. Instead, the energy is transformed from some internal energy to kinetic energy without being transferred to another system.

The only energy that is transferred is the energy that goes into the other object. The column gains KE but the wall does not. So more energy is transferred to the column and therefore more work is done.

Comment: So appolo 10 did no work?

Comment: It accelerated a lot of air. Of course if you want to consider the boosters to be separate systems from the capsule and payload then there is a lot of work.

Comment: *The “work” that you do accelerating yourself doesn’t transfer energy, so it isn’t actually work* You sure about this? Intuitively it seems to me that pulling on the string exerts a force, and I also move, so there should be work done by $W = F \cdot S$.

Comment: @Allure if you look more carefully you are applying a force on the rope. At the point of contact $S=0$ so $W=0$. Your center of mass moves but the force is not applied there. So no energy transferred and $S=0$ both give the same answer: no work

Comment: Are you saying that in my reference frame I do no work? If so then in my reference frame everything else (including the wall) would be accelerating towards me as I pull on the rope. I can't possibly store that much internal energy. Does that break energy conservation?

Comment: @Allure your frame is non inertial. Energy is not generally conserved in non inertial frames